# "zip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python

Всем привет, простите, что приходится возиться с новичком))
В общем, учу Python по книге A Byte of Python (Russian)
Версия 2.01
Swaroop C H (Translated by Vladimir Smolyar).
При написании простой программы, которая создает резервные копии файлов у меня вывелась такая вот ошибка. Архиватор стоит у меня WinRAR. Проверил переменную Path, путь к папке этого архиватора там тоже есть. Прошу помочь!

```
import os 
import time


# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

[image: Переменная Path]

Comment: Код - текстом, а не скриншотом, где ничего не разобрать.

Comment: А вы уверены, что в вашей WinRAR папке лежит исполняемый файл zip.exe? Поскольку ваша программа пытается вызвать этот самый исполняемый файл.

Comment: Для работы этого скрипта нужна консольная утилита zip.

Answer (score 2):

Пишу пост впервые, поэтому сильно не ругайте, сам только учусь (стаж - 1 неделя :D ).
Я смог заставить работать WinRar за место Zip'а, но немного изменил код, у меня он получился таким:

```
import os 
import time
source = ['D:\ggames'] 
target_dir = 'D:\\Backup' 
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "rar a {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0: 
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target) 
else: 
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

В 3 и 4 строчке изменил путь, предыдущий меня не устраивал, пускай не так красиво, но вроде работает.

В переменной zip_command (7 строка) изменил zip на rar (Гениально) аргумент поставил "а", то бишь создать архив, по факту это все изменения.

В переменную path добавил путь к WinRar, у меня он такой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После в терминале (использую Visual Studio Code) нужно указать путь к папке, (команда вызова rar не работает, выдает ту же самую ошибку что нет такой команды. Подскажите кто в теме, я в силу отсутствия опыта и знаний сказать точно не могу :) ) путь таков:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска программы все работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь у Вас тоже заработает, пишите если что-то не так.

UPD:
Понял причину почему rar не работает через path, хотя путь добавлен был верно, проверил догадку на счет пути к самой директории WinRar, он был: C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe
Видимо из-за пробела в Program Files (А может из-за еще чего) было невозможно вызвать rar из командной строки. Перенес директорию WinRar в другое место (чтобы путь директории был без пробелов), поставил новый путь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вуаля - rar вызывается, программа работает без костыля с указанием папки в терминале.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикладывайте, пожалуйста, код в виде текста, а не в виде скриншота.

Answer (score 1):

Переменные среды и в частности переменная Path определяет только пути по умолчанию, где ваша операционная система будет искать файлы. Исполняемые файлы эти программ потом можно будет вызвать из консоли не прописывая полный путь.

К примеру на скриншоте ниже я вызываю программу "блокнот" по ее полному пути `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`. Если же у меня в переменной Path будет стоять путь "C:\Windows\System32\", то я могу вызвать блокнот просто написав "notepad" без полного пути. В обоих случаях откроется стандартный блокнот Windows.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вы выполняете `os.system("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")`, то вы просто передаете операционной системе команду `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` так, как будто это выполняется в консоли.

Исходя из вышесказанного, ваш скрипт просто передает команду ОС, а она не может найти программу zip.exe и выполнить ее, поскольку ее нет в папке WinRAR. Да и заменить один *.exe на другой не факт, что выйдет, полскольку *.exe имеют определенный набор инструкций.

Поэтому вам либо надо установить консольную утилиту zip: https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/ Либо осознать вышесказанное и продолжить изучать Python дальше.

Comment: а куда нужно распаковывать эту утилиту?

Comment: @HikkaNote я никогда не ставил эту утилиту за ненадобностью. По идее в любую папку, на которую потом прописать в Path. Обычно она устанавливается на Linux из репозитория дистрибутива, а под Windows не могу сказать ничего и заработает ли вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой и предлагаю решение, которое помогло мне.

В ходе многочисленных опытов стало ясно, что некоторые функции командной строки работают, только если запустить её от имени администратора.[image: Командная строка]

То есть сама команда, передаваемая командной строке была корректной. Это можно было проверить, вставив её вручную в командную строку, запущенную от имени администратора.
Попробовал запустить тот же код, но на простом IDLE (вместо PyCharm) - заработало.

Проблема была, очевидно, в PyCharm'е.

Решением стал запуск редактора кода от имени администратора.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа

Answer (score 0):

Хочу подчеркнуть один момент:
У меня тоже была эта проблема и я долго возился с ней на своем ноуте, я скачивал и zip и WinRAR, и указывал правильную директорию но все равно не работало, и в перерывах своих попыток я ноут не выключал а просто прикрывал крышку и он был в спящем режиме, потом я решил перезагрузить систему Windows и попытался снова и все получилось. В общем рекомендую перезагружать систему после установки доп. ПО и изменений директории.